# Trying to print separate models one on top of the other using PrusaSlicer

Tags: prusaslicer, multi-material

I'm currently using Cura for one printer (Hellbot Magna SE, essentially an Ender clone) and PrusaSlicer for another (Artillery Hornet).

I first learned this method for multicolored prints with Cura on [CHEP's channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_Mohd7JLzw) since I have had awful accidents with manual filament changes in the past, given that my Hellbot printer doesn't understand the M600 command and I have to use M0 pauses instead. this way works great and gives me a lot of peace of mind since now I can leave the printer unattended for a bit knowing it will finish printing then turn the nozzle and bed off, home on all axes and just sit there idle until I come back and start the next print on top, this one sliced with the corresponding Z Offset value so as to not collide with the one currently sitting on the bed.

I would like to do the same on my Hornet, but I use PrusaSlicer with it since the builtin profile is so much better, and I can't figure out how to do it. I have located the Z Offset setting, but [the only way to be able to lift objects from the platter seems to be by making them "parts" of another one](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/how-to-lift-object-from-the-print-bed_245192), and in that case I lose the option to disable the "Printable" flag that lets me hide the different components of the object so I can slice them and export them as separate files.

> **Note:** While typing this it just occurred to me maybe setting the
> corresponding Z Offset for the object that goes on top of the one
> already on the bed *without making it a part* but rather the only
> thing on the platter might work? Perhaps this isn't necessary for
> PrusaSlicer to generate the code that I need. I'll test this tomorrow
> but anything that implies possible collisions will always make me a
> bit nervous. I will update the question with the result of the test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are asking something that has been asked before; does ["Pile up objects and attach them for mass 3D printing"](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/pile-up-objects-and-attach-them-for-mass-3d-printing) answer your question?

Comment: @0scar thank you but not really. I want separate files that will print one on top of the other so I don't have to deal with pauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer myself since I tested my hypothesis today.
Turns out in PrusaSlicer you don't need to "elevate" the model from the build plate and make it sit on the other model in order to be able to print on top of it. Just the Z Offset option is enough.

Here's what I did:

1. Load the first part that will sit at the bottom.
2. Right click it and Add Part(s). This will be just for reference.
3. Take note of the height of each part (this will be the Z Offset for the next print)
4. Remove all parts and import the files as separate models.
5. Now you can generate separate files for each of them. First one will of course have an offset of 0, next one will have an offset equal to the previous ones' heights, and so on.

As an important note, **only have your bed on for the first print, afterwards always leave it off as this will start to deform the print from below**. I recommend you use glue stick or hairspray to help the adhesion instead.