# What is PrusaSlicer showing as the world Z position?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, z-axis, prusaslicer

I'm continuing [my previous question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/trying-to-print-separate-models-one-on-top-of-the-other-using-prusaslicer) with another one.

I managed to figure out how to tell the slicer to consider a Z Offset to be able to print on top of a previous print, but the prusa interface is confusing me.

The model I want to print is 1.5 mm in height. The model I'm printing it on is 2.4 mm in height, so that's my Z Offset. Up to here it's okay. The issue is that when I import the model I want to print now, it shows its position in Z as 0.75. This makes no sense.

[image: the coordinates]

I checked the model on 3DBuilder to see if it had extra space under it for some reason, but it has none. Cura has no issue dropping the model on the buildplate but Prusa is showing this weird measurement.

What is Prusa measuring as the position on Z? I thought the position meant where the bottom of the model sits, and the platter visualization does show this, but the number does not, it should be 0.

[image: the platter]

ETA: Using the cut function and cutting the model exactly at 0.75 solved the problem and it is now displaying at 0 on Z but it still makes no sense.